# Issue with status bar using cordova inappbrowser and ios 11 and iPhone x

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, ios11, inappbrowser, iphone-x

I have a cordova app that I am trying to update to use with the new iPhone x and I am having issues opening a external page with inappbrowser. I am using the latest xcode iPhone X simulator. If I change the target to "_self" it works fine but then i don't have the loadstop event which I am dependent on.

Notice the gray space between the white and red page.The attached video explains it better https://www.dropbox.com/s/fnsjz71dssqcr56/bug.mov?dl=0.
[image]

The cover image and everything else looks great.

here is my cordova config

```
    <preference name="Fullscreen" value="True" />
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-7.0.1" />
<preference name="KeepRunning" value="True" />
<preference name="ShowTitle" value="False" />
<preference name="InAppBrowserStorageEnabled" value="True" />
<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
<preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#ffffff" />
<preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="black-translucent" />
<preference name="deployment-target" value="10" />
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="2000" />
<preference name="AllowBackForwardNavigationGestures" value="false" />
<feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
</feature>
<feature name="StatusBar">
    <param name="ios-package" onload="true" value="CDVStatusBar" />
</feature>
<preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="1.1.7" />
<plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" spec="2.0.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="4.1.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="~1.3.3" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-touch-id" spec="~3.2.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="2.3.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine" spec="~1.1.4" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser-wkwebview" spec="^1.0.4" />
<engine name="ios" spec="~4.5.3" />
```

the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy">
    <meta name="viewport" content="viewport-fit=cover", initial-scale=1, width=device-width">
    <link href="content/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title>Wealth Access</title>   
</head>
<body>    
    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/TouchID.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

the javascript

```js
function onDeviceReady() {
        if (window.plugins.uniqueDeviceID) {
            registerDevice();
            setBotificationBadges();
        }
        loadSite();
    }


function loadSite() {

        if (ref) {
            return;
        }

        window.open = cordova.InAppBrowser.open;

        ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(/* my url */, '_blank', 'location=no,toolbar=no,zoom=no,disallowoverscroll=yes');


}
```

Here is the page it is loading

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>




        <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />

    <title>Wealth Access | Login</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="/Content/images/wealthaccess-icon.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/Content/images/wealthaccess-icon.png" />


    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, viewport-fit=cover">

</head>

<body>

        
<div style="background-color: red">test page</div>
       
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: +1 I'm plagued with the same issue. To give some extra context to those not watching the video: the inappbrowser native web view itself is adding the top spacing. If you inspect the web page via Safari Dev Tools, you can clearly see that the html takes up all of the available space in the web view. It's as if inappbrowser is trying to pad for the status bar, but gets this incorrect for iPhone X & the dreaded notch.

Comment: As predicted, the offending line in cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/CDVInAppBrowser.m is `statusBarFrame.size.height = STATUSBAR_HEIGHT;`. Changing that to zero removes the spacing; but now it'll be up to your app to handle the status bar.

Comment: Note that based on what browser config you are using, there are (now) multiple references to STATUSBAR_HEIGHT in the cordova-plugin-inappbrowser directory. Changing them to a larger value (40) fixed the problem for me (on iPhone 11 simulator) by allowing room for the "notch" at the top.